# Javascript pass object to function issue

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I have an object that I am trying to pass but not working:

```
     var inf1= { ID: "34343434" };
```

What I like to do in javascript is to pass this object to a function .
I am not sure how to do this.

I have the calling function as such

```
  function getinf(inf1)
  {
     var samp = JSON.parse(inf1);
     alert(samp.ID);
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `JSON.parse()` on a JSON formatted string.  You don't use it on a javascript object.  JSON is a text format.

Your `inf1` variable is already a javascript object so there is no need to parse it.

This should work just fine:

```
var inf1= { ID: "34343434" };

function getinf(item)
{
    alert(item.ID);
}

getinf(inf1);
```

Comment: i.e.`function getinf(inf1) { alert(inf1.ID); }`

Answer (score 0):

Careful, a few things:

`JSON.parse()` is for strings

And to pass the value you could do:

```
var inf1= { ID: "34343434" };
  function getinf(obj)
  {
     //code using obj...
     //you can acess obj.ID if you want
  }

getInf(inf1); //or any obj you want
```

or

```
var inf1= { ID: "34343434" };
function getinf()
{
   //code using inf1...
}
```